# OptionalAttribute parameter's default value?

Tags: c#, default-value, optional-parameters

MSDN's VS2010 [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) tells us about optional parameters in C#, showing code like I'd expect:

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required, 
    string optionalstr = "default string", 
    int optionalint = 10)
```

Ok, but it also says:

> You can also declare optional
> parameters by using the .NET
> OptionalAttribute class.
> OptionalAttribute parameters do not
> require a default value.

I read [MSDN's OptionalAttribute page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.optionalattribute), and done searches online (which shows lots of people claiming OptionalAttribute parameters can't be consumed by C# -- I'm guessing these comments were made before C# 4?), but I can't find the answer to two questions:

If I use OptionalAttribute to define a C# parameter as optional:

1. what value will be used if I call that method and don't specify that parameter's value?
2. will that value be evaluated at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Run it in debug and check it's value. I would suspect null.

Comment: Well, I'd suspect `default(T)` which is null or zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules are this:

- For parameters of type `object`, [`Type.Missing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing.aspx) is passed.
- For other reference types, `null` is passed.
- For value types, the [default of the value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=VS.80).aspx) is passed.

  - For [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) this means that you will get a `Nullable<T>` instance which is equal to `null` (the [`HasValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) will return `false`)

Note that in the case of everything except parameters of type `object`, it's the equivalent of `default(T)`.

I was a little surprised, as the [C# 4.0 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/6/7E6A548C-9C20-4C80-B3B8-860FAF20887A/CSharp%204.0%20Specification.doc) didn't indicate what the outcome would be, and I'd expect it to be there.

Also (as [indicated by Scott Rippey in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416216/optionalattribute-parameters-default-value/3416327#comment11416192_3416327)), this is evaluated at compile-time, this is not a run-time operation, meaning that if you have calls to this method in other assemblies which are already deployed, and you change the optional value, the default passed to the method will *not* change unless you compile everything that makes the call against the method in the assembly.

Comment: You should also mention that this is evaluated at compile time. The compiler actually inserts the default values into the **calling** code when compiling.

Comment: I think it's *also* worthwhile mentioning that when invoking a method by reflection, you pass in `Type.Missing` and the appropriate value will be inserted in the called method at *run* time. So it can be done at run time as well as compile time. (Reference: [`Type.Missing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.missing.aspx))